# I committed a crime against the Weapons Act in Germany - Can I travel there?

Tags: germany, weapons, air-travel

I bought a butterfly knife in Poland (where it is legal) and had an overnight stop in Germany. I checked my bags out from the airport that night, then checked them back in the morning.

The knife was confiscated, and I had to sign papers, make a statement, etc.
I am currently pending investigation.

I have a business trip in Germany in a few months, which I am certain is sooner than my sentencing. Can I fly to Germany before my sentencing? USA citizen, if it matters.

https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/waffg_2002/BJNR397010002.html

Comment: I would call the U.S. Embassy in Berlin OR the U.S. State Department (in D.C.) and play phone tree.  If you do go and are arrested, make sure you request a representative form the consulate (like you would request a lawyer, as you are entitled to that right.)  Shut the hell up with the cops until both an attorney and someone from the U.S. Consulate talk to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Travel.SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in most cases it depends on the details.

The length of a blade (> 44mm and width > 10) is important and the circumstances.

Assume a **fine** to something up to € 10000, but a sentence up to 3 years is also possible.

In Germany it is not **crime** (anything that can be fined or minimal sentence is less than 1 year is not a crime).

I assume that they took your home address and let you leave the country, which alone is a sign that it not a crime.

Since you were so smart to place this in your luggage, where it **garantied** to be found by airport security, you will probably get something in the range of the minimal fine.
You also cooperated by giving a statement, which will assist to lessen the fine (you were after all caught red handed).

Having it on your person in a public space, the fine would have be higher.

Swinging it around among peaple in a threatening manner, will lead you into the range of a sentence.

When the fine arrives, there will be bank transaction form.
Go to the next post office or bank and pay it, retaining the receipt.

Border control will not be interested in you (they only get alerts for proper criminals).
Customs (Zoll) could be interested to enforce the fine, show them the receipt.

Pay the fine and get on with your life.

---

As to the **U.S. Consulate** (forget Embassy, State Department: they deal only in diplomatic affairs) all they will tell you is

- you must obey the laws of the country you are in
- assisted in getting an English speaking lawyer when requested
- send you bill for their efforts

A Consulate deals with citizen affairs (administration, assistance).

Most Embassies have a Cousulate department inside, but not all.
In Berlin it does not. The Cousulate is about 20 Kilometres away from the Embassy.

The right to call them is based on the Vienna Conventions 1815 and 1961. All countries that reconised these conventions are required to allow a foreigner to contact their Cousulate.
A dual citizen, when inside the country where they are a citizen, do not have this right.

Comment: this question should be in travel.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think the translation of the technical term "Verbrechen" with "crime" is good. As far as I know "crime" does have a broader meaning, esp. in a non-technical context.

Comment: The fact that it is not a crime means that questioner won't be prevented from entering. A 1:1 'translation' of these terms are always difficult. What I gave was the German definition of 'Verbrechen', which could cause refusal of enter or Visa. The red line is a sentence of 2 years as far as I remember.

Comment: Where is defined that someone in investigations because of a "Verbrechen" cannot enter Germany?

Comment: § 5(1)(3) AufenthG Against the public interest. Decision is based on what is found in the persons Criminal record (Führungszeugnis). A judgement has to be made about the likelihood of a continuation of criminal behaviour. When yes an entry in the SIS database can be made. § 15 (3) states that these rules also applies for persons who don't need a visa.

Comment: A single serious crime (assumed often as sentence >= 2 years), can lead to a entry ban. A single offence mostly likly not. The same offence,  done regularly, could lead to an entry ban. This a 'discretionary decision'  (Ermessungsentscheidung). Source Commentary AufenthG, 2009

Comment: The OP says the investigation is pending. So there is nothing in the Fürhungszeugnis now.

Comment: @K-HB Accourding to the comments of the AufenthG (and elsewhere) , pending cases can be listed in the central criminal records, but can only be seen by high authorities. Judges are stated as one authority and I assume State prosecuter and Foreigners authority may also. The last are authorized when processing visa / residence permit. This the base of my statement that the Border control (Bundespolizei) will have no altert since it is a one time affair. What happens if he doesn't react to the final decision in another affair.